# Linux drops UDP packets

Tags: linux, udp, packets

I have written a C++ tool for my linux machine which receives UDP (OSC) packets and sends them back immediately (thats the only thing it does). But it seems that there is some amount of dropped packets. When I send 100 packets to my linux (from another machine), mostly only 64 packets are returned. I have looked at the incoming packets with tcpdump. It tells me the following:

```
64 packets captured
64 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

So where are they?

Comment: *Any* host can drop a UDP datagram.

Comment: Yes. But there was not dropped anything. At least the output says it.

Answer (score 0):

UDP, by design, does not guarantee that the packets arrive at the destination. The packets missing might no have reached your machine at all, and thus will not appear in the incoming packets. 
UDP is mostly used for streams and games, as loosing a few packets does not really matter.

If you want to be sure that all the packets arrive, you should use TCP.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes. But why do always arrive exactly only 64 Pakets? This seems to be a kind of Network buffer problem?

Comment: My bad, I didn't see that it was always the same number of packets. I guess it can be several things, from timeout/validity of the sent packets to buffer problems.